# MediaWiki: How do I force MediaWiki to update a certain Category:XXX page?

Tags: mediawiki

Is it possible to force MediaWiki update a certain Category:XXX page? For example, a lot of pages used templates that referred a category "Templates" causing every such page to be included to the "Template" category. That's obviously wrong. I have already fixed the templates by wrapping the "Templates" category into the noinclude tag, so now every page that use these templates are no longer categorized as "Templates". That's fine.

```
Article source:
    {{stub}}

Template source BEFORE the fix:
    This page is a stub
    [[Category:Templates]]
Rendered article BEFORE the fix:
    This page is a stub
    Categories: Templates | Stubs
Category Templates BEFORE the fix:
    Article
    Template:Stub

Template source AFTER the fix:
    This page is a stub
    <noinclude>[[Category:Templates]]</noinclude>
Rendered article AFTER the fix:
    This page is a stub
    Categories: Stubs
Category Templates AFTER the fix:
    Article <--- this is wrong
    Template:Stub
```

But the list in the Category:Template seems to be frozen for really long time. I do remember that I had a similar case a half year ago, and I clearly watched the number of pages decreased slowly, but constantly. Now it got stuck. Is any categorization update status page available? (I'm almost sure that I remember someone told me it's performed by a background job) Or what am I doing wrong?

- MediaWiki: 1.23.6
- PHP: 5.4.38

Thanks in advance.

---

UPDATE: See [here](http://www.mediawiki.org/w/index.php?title=Thread:Project:Support_desk/Is_it_possible_to_force_MediaWiki_update_a_certain_Category:XXX_page%3F&lqt_method=thread_history) for more information in addition to the best answer here.

Comment: Are you sure you [set up the job queue](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Job_queue#Set_up)?

Comment: @Nemo I had not the hosting account at the time, and had no opportunity to configure like that. However, I bet I worked before I asked the question.

Comment: 1 year later: "it worked", of course. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have two suggestions to try:

### Purge

It looks like the update is showing on the article but not the category page, so a simple [purge](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Purge) may do the trick.

To do that, pass the `action=purge` parameter to the *category* URL. (An easy way is to click the edit link to open the edit window, and replace `action=edit` with `action=purge` in the URL.)

### Null edit

If the article is not updating after changing the template, your problem is the [job queue](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Job_queue), which can take a while to filter through, depending on load. On a case-by-case basis, performing a [null edit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Purge#Null_edit) on the *article* should solve your problem. From [Meta-Wiki](https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Help:Dummy_edit#Null_edit):

> The most useful side-effect of a null edit is that it updates category pages, taking into account categories transcluded via templates. If a category has been added to or removed from a template since it was last transcluded on a page, then purging the cache will not update the category contents, but a null edit to the page (not the category) will – see [Help:Category#Adding a category by using a template](https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Help:Category#Adding_a_category_by_using_a_template).

To do that, edit the article in question but make no changes. If you save the page, it will look like nothing happened (nothing is recorded in the page history or your contributions list), but that bypasses the job queue and forces the page to update based on the new version of the template.

Comment: Wow, really nice answer! Thanks for the suggestions! It's all strange. Purging had no effect at all, unfortunately. Null edit really does the trick, but it seems that I have to null-edit every page and that's tedious. I have just null-edited on article, and, true, the number of the pages in the article has decreased by one. Is there a way to force the update for the rest? For curiosity sake, I've also checked `api.php?action=query&meta=siteinfo&siprop=statistics&format=jsonfm` as told in the job queue article, and the number of jobs is constantly big: 1577. It looks weird to me.

Comment: @LyubomyrShaydariv Hmm, that is strange. How long was it between when you edited the template and when you null edited the pages?

Comment: About 8 hours -- nothing changed. I'm also trying to null-edit following your suggestion, and noticed that some null-edit pages do not trigger the category to update. Can't see what is different between the changed and the unchanged pages. (The only difference I guess is the size of the pages and the number of templates used on these pages -- these pages are relatively large and use up to 15-20 templates per page).

Comment: Yes, I suspect it has something to do with [template limits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Template_limits).

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong in my previous comment: the null-edit seems to work always. The unaffected pages still have templates with the category. I just didn't notice it. But I'm not yet sure...

Comment: The number of the remaining articles is not very big for null-editing. So this is fine. Thank you! :)

Comment: This is wrong. 1) you need to purge the article, not the category page. Purging a page updates updates its usage in various indexes (categories, "what links here" etc). Purging a template does *not* update every single page categorized into it; that wouldn't scale and is exactly the kind of thing a job queue is for. 2) a null edit does not do anything useful beyond what a purge already does (in this case, anyway).

Comment: The root problem is probably that a job queue runner has not been set up. See [the job queue manual](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Job_queue).

Comment: @Tgr Sorry, my original quote wasn't clear because I put the quote in the wrong section. 1) I suggested purge on the category page because the article had updated to reflect the template edit, but not the category, so I don't think purging the article would do any good. I never suggested purging the template. 2) The quoted text from Meta-Wiki seems to indicate that null edit does what was requested.

Comment: What's actually needed here is purging the article (or running the job queue worker). Doing a null edit on the article is a more expensive version of purging it that also does some extra stuff that's not relevant here. Purging the category does not do anything useful. (I wrote template above when I really meant category; sorry for the confusion.)